# Extract only text of a certain font type from a .docx file using Python

Tags: python, docx

I want to extract all text of type 'Arial' from my .docx file. This is currently what I have but it's not producing any output (most of the text in the document is of type 'Arial').

```
from docx import *

document = Document('word.docx')
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        if run.style == "Arial":
            print(run.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Style* is distinct from *font* in documents.  Style in word means the application of a *named style* (like 'heading').  Sadly most people don't use styles, but just grab a region of text and change the font.

From a bit of digging with a test document, it seems that the `font` attribute is what you are looking for.  For a document like this:

```
Default Font.

Arial Font.

Default Arial Default Courier.
```

I can find the non-default font sections:

```py
>>> from docx import Document
>>> from itertools import chain

>>> doc = Document("test.docx")
>>> runs = list(chain.from_iterable(list(p.runs) for p in doc.paragraphs))
>>> [r.font.name for r in runs]
[None, None, 'Arial', None, None, 'Arial', None, 'Courier New', None]
>>> [r.text for r in runs]
['Default Font.', '', 'Arial Font.\n', '\n', 'Default ', 'Arial', ' Default ', 'Courier.', '']
```